# How to set a default value for hashtable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, hashtable, default

Is there anyway to set a hashtable's default value in ruby after filling the hashtable with JSON.parse() in ruby?

Comment: Must be that famous hour-of-horrible-questions-on-StackOverflow time again

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, I don't think how you got the hash is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a hash's default value with the method [Hash#default_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

For example, suppose:

```
h = { :a=>1, :b=>2 }
```

and if `h` does not have the key `k` you want `h[k]` to return an empty array. You could do that like so:

```
h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { [] } # could write h.default_proc = ->(*) { [] }

h[:a] #=> 1
h[:b] #=> 2
h[:c] #=> []
h #=> { :a=>1, :b=>2 } # h is unchanged
```

If you want to add the key and value to the hash:

```
h.default_proc = ->(h,k) { h[k] = [] }

h[:a] #=> 1
h[:b] #=> 2
h[:c] #=> []
h #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>[]}
```

Comment: If arguments are irrelevant, they could also be ignored with `h.default_proc = -> (*) { [] }`.